# Add extra footer to sphinx_rtd_theme

Tags: python-sphinx

I am attempting to add an extra footer to the `sphinx_rtd_theme` in Sphinx, running on my local machine. I have created a file `footer.html` and stored it in `source/_templates`. The file contents are given here:

```
{% extends '!footer.html' %} {% block extrafooter %} {{super}} <!--
 <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/"><img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-sa/4.0/88x31.png" /></a><br />This work is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/">Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International License</a>.
 --> {% endblock %}
```

I expected this markup to display after the `default sphinx_rtd_theme` footer but only the default footer was displayed.

I am running Windows 10 with Fall Creators Update and Python 3.6.5 - 64 bit.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the Html was embedded in an Html comment. Removing the comment made it start working. The comment was there because I took the fragment verbatim from another post.